# Is there a way to make a code requiring large size variables efficient (and run faster) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I’m doing this operation:

```
m=exp((a-b’).^2);
n=m*(x.*y);
d=m*y;
```

Where a,b,x,y are column vectors. m becomes a matrix, n is a column vector, d is a column vector. This code doesn’t run for large a and b because the matrix formed by a-b’ exceeds size limits of MATLAB. So I tried using a for loop:

```
n=zeros(length(a),1);
d=n;
for i=1:length(a)
    t=(exp((a(i)-b).^2).*y)’;
    n(i)=t*x;
    d(i)=sum(temp);
end
```

Is there any way to make this efficient? I have to run this loop a lot of times so the total time taken is an hour or so.

Comment: Note that the limit of MATLAB is likely the limit of your computer. Your computer likely can not handle such variable sizes because you don't have enough RAM. Computational cost vs memory is the standard fight in this type of code. Things can't be faster and more memory efficient unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a less defined type you will use less memory and hence may be allowed a bigger matrix: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html

Maybe you can also use a parfor loop to use all your CPU cores.

Comment: I don’t think I can use a less defined type because the changes are of a small order of magnitude. I shall look into parfor loop. Thank you.